# When written user_id on address bar does not exist, redirect root_url on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I log in to the system, on address bar, I see http://localhost:3000/admins/15, but when I write `43214321` instead of `15`, I get the following error:

> Couldn't find Patient with 'id'=43214321 .

**This is my code:**

```
def show
    @admin = Admin.find(params[:id].to_i)
    conversations = @admin.conversations
    @patient_conversations = conversations
            .where.not(:patient_id => nil)
            .joins(:messages)
            .group("conversations.id")
            .order("max(messages.created_at) DESC")
    @doctor_conversations = conversations
            .where(:patient_id => nil)
            .where(:agency_id => nil)
            .joins(:messages)
            .group("conversations.id")
            .order("max(messages.created_at) DESC")
    @agency_conversations = conversations 
            .where(:patient_id => nil)
            .where.not(:agency_id => nil)
            .joins(:messages)
            .group("conversations.id")
            .order("max(messages.created_at) DESC")
end
```

How can I redirect to `root_url` if the record doesn't exist?

Comment: Why is the error message about the `Patient` class, but your code uses the `Admin` class?

Comment: yeah You say it didn't work. I think you are looking in the wrong place? Where is patient coming from?

Comment: are you a former PHP programmer? #just_a_thought

Comment: So where did you add the `rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`find` will raise an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` exception if the record doesn't exist.](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find) You can rescue that exception and redirect like this:

```
def show
  @admin = Admin.find(params[:id])
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  redirect_to root_url
end
```

Comment: Why not? It should work... do you get a different error?

Comment: I edited controller, I do not know why it did not work. :( maybe I should add more for rescure ActiveRecord

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need to know that `.find` method throws exception called `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` which you need to handle/catch and respond to the user in proper way.

> To know more about exception handling in rails watch this https://cbabhusal.wordpress.com/2015/08/03/ruby-on-rails-exception-handling-best-practices/

Second thing, you do not need to do `.to_i` for `params[:id]` its done by `Activerecord` for you.

```
def show
  @admin = Admin.find(params[:id])
end
```

in `your_controller`

```
rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound do |exception|
  redirect_to root_url 
end
```

or You can do it in simple way as described by `@Mischa` in another answer

If you donot want it to throw exception then you can do like below, however this is not recommended

```
def show
  @admin = Admin.find_by(id: params[:id]) # returns nil if no record found
  unless @admin
    # respond with an error message
      redirect_to root_url 
  end
end
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_by

Comment: If you want to use `find_by`, it should be `Admin.find_by(id: params[:id])`

Comment: its optional.. you can use it as `Admin.find_by(params[:id])` also, try it :)

Comment: When you do that the generated query is: `SELECT  "admins".* FROM "admins" WHERE ({params[:id]}) LIMIT 1`. So you just get the first row, not the row you're looking for. So, it's not optional.

Comment: oh yes, it looks like so, thanks for the info.. I misunderstood this

Answer (score 0):

Just change `find` to `find_by_id` and return direct if Admin is not exist with this ID:

```
def show
  @admin = Admin.find_by_id(params[:id]) # no need to say .to_i
  # here we say "and return" so code not continue to exctute and raise double rendering.
  redirect_to root_url and return unless @admin 
  # ..... continue here as normal and admin should be exist
end
```